# Cannot make that scroll bar shows frame untill the bottom

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to create a pop up help window for a tool. I managed to add the scrollbar to a frame that contains canvas and label widget. However that Scrollbar does not shows the img_canvas_3 that I added.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

help_window = tkinter.Tk()

help_window.title("Help")
help_window.geometry("400x800")

#frame.grid(row=0,column=0)
canvas=Canvas(help_window,bg='red',width=300,height=800,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))
scroll_y = Scrollbar(help_window, orient="vertical", command = canvas.yview)
frame=Frame(canvas,width=300,height=800, bg="green")
description_label = Label(frame, text = "\n\tMy Tool\n",anchor = "w").pack(side = TOP, fill = "both")

introduction = "This tool provides a basic workflow"   
introduction_text = Label(frame, text = introduction, anchor = "w", font = "Verdana 10", bg="yellow").pack(fill = "both")

label_1 = Label(frame, text = "Input Data 1", anchor = "w", font = "Verdana 10", justify=CENTER).pack(fill = "both")

img_canvas_1 = Canvas(frame, bg = "black", height = 300, width = 300)
img_canvas_1.pack(side = TOP)

label_2 = Label(frame, text = "Input Data 2", anchor = "w", font = "Verdana 10", justify = CENTER).pack(fill = "both")

img_canvas_2 = Canvas(frame, bg = "black", height = 300, width = 300)
img_canvas_2.pack(side = TOP)

label_3 = Label(frame, text = "Input Data 3", anchor = "w", font = "Verdana 10", justify = CENTER).pack(fill = "both")
img_canvas_3 = Canvas(frame, bg = "black", height = 300, width = 300)
img_canvas_3.pack(side = TOP)

canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor = 'nw', window = frame)
canvas.update_idletasks
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'),
                            yscrollcommand = scroll_y.set)
canvas.pack(fill = 'both', expand = TRUE, side = 'left')
scroll_y.pack(fill = 'y', side = 'right')

help_window.mainloop()
```

I expected to have the scroll bar working, basically showing all the widgets and elements in the frame as I am adding more and more. That is only true for the untill img_canvas_2

Does anyone have an idea why this is not the case with my code? I tried by playing around with the scrollregion parameter in the canvas variable, but it did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `canvas.update_idletasks` needs to be `canvas.update_idletasks()`.

Comment: Thank you. I corrected that line in my code and things are now up and running.